# Display all category name together woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I tried to show all the category name together with this code.
But it shows me only one category (uncategorized). I want to show category names like - category 1, category 2, category 3 and so on. Can anyone help to find the problem?

```
<?php
  $categories = get_categories();

  if (!empty( $categories)) {
       foreach( $categories as $category ) {
       echo ''<span class="simple-news-categories">' . $category->name . '</span>';
       }          
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get_categories()` won't return all the categories. It will return only that category which has post associated with it. Which means, the function will return only the categories, that have been used in the post. So you need to set the argument `hide_empty` to false.

Try this

```
$categories = get_categories( array('hide_empty' => false));
$categories = wp_list_pluck($categories, 'name');
echo '<span class="simple-news-categories">'.implode(', ', $categories).'</span>';
```

**UPDATE**

If your requirement is to show WooCommerce product categories, then use the following.

```
$categories = get_categories( array('hide_empty' => false, 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'));
$categories = wp_list_pluck($categories, 'name');
echo '<span class="simple-news-categories">'.implode(', ', $categories).'</span>';
```

Comment: still I'm getting only one category (Uncategorized). I need to show all category together.

Comment: Ok. The above code will show the categories in the Post. If your requirement is to show WooCommerce product categories, then you have to use `get_categories( array('hide_empty' => false, 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'));`

Comment: it's working. but I need to echo using a loop

Comment: It's working now. just changed little bit 


`$categories = get_categories( array(
                        'hide_empty' => true, 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat')); foreach( $categories as $category ) { echo '<a class="btn btn-light">' . $category->name . '</a>';}  `

Comment: Glad it worked.